# Cómo agrupar 3 tablas mysql para obtener visitas diarias únicas para un autor de articulos (items)?

Tags: mysql

Tengo 3 tablas de Mysql.

**Visitas**

Registra los IP de los usuario, fecha, los ID de los item que han visitado.

```
| id | item_id |   ip_address    |       fecha         |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  |    3    | 123.123.123.123 | 2018-03-01 17:00:30 |
| 1  |    1    | 123.123.123.123 | 2018-03-03 17:00:30 |
| 1  |    5    | 000.000.000.000 | 2018-03-04 17:00:30 |
| 1  |    4    | 123.123.123.123 | 2018-03-01 17:00:30 |
| 1  |    4    | 999.999.999.999 | 2018-03-02 17:00:30 |
| 1  |    1    | 888.888.888.888 | 2018-03-12 17:00:30 |
```

**Items**

Tiene datos sobre los items, entre ellos: tiene el author_id (el ID del creador del item).

```
| id | autor_id |
-----------------
| 1  |     2    |
| 2  |     1    |
| 3  |     1    |
| 4  |     2    |
| 5  |     1    |
```

**Autores**

Esta tabla tiene la lista de autores (creadores) con sus datos.

```
| id | name |  surname  |
-------------------------
| 1  | Jose | Rodriguez |
| 2  | Jesus|   Abadia  |
```

Necesito obtener: cuantas visitas diarias unicas un autor ha obtenido en los ultimo 30 dias. Esto es a lo que he llegado:

```
SELECT item_id, ip_address FROM `visitas`
WHERE 1
    AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY item_id, ip_address
```

Por ejemplo:

```
|    fecha   |  visitas  | 
--------------------------
| 2018-03-01 |     2     |
| 2018-03-02 |     10    |
| 2018-03-02 |     8     |
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

si lo único que necesitas es la consulta SQL, puedes utilizar la siguiente:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(W.fecha,  '%Y-%m%-%d' ) AS fecha, COUNT( * ) AS visitas
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT V.fecha, V.ip_address
    FROM visita V, Item I
    WHERE V.item_id = I.id
    AND I.autor_id =1
) as W
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(W.fecha,  '%Y-%m%-%d' )
ORDER BY W.fecha 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Con esta consulta obtienes el numero de visitas que un autor recibió por día de direcciones IP diferentes en los últimos 30 dias, el único dato de entrada es el id del autor, si necesitas que te explique alguna parte del código puedo editar la respuesta, espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. :D

Answer (score 0):

La solucion propuesta por @the-beaker funciona perfectamente excepto las ultimas dos lineas. Me Causan el siguiente error:

> **#1055 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'W.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**

Pero modificando un poco funciona bien!

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(W.date,  '%Y-%m%-%d' ) AS date, COUNT( * ) AS visitas
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT V.date, V.ip_address
    FROM views_unique V, items I
    WHERE V.item_id = I.id
    AND I.author_id = 7
    AND V.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
) as W
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(W.date,  '%Y-%m%-%d' )
```

Comment: Hola, puede que el problema sea la versión de mysql que utilizas, en esa consulta utilice la versión 5.0.11, tal vez tu versión sea mas antigua.

Comment: Hola @the-breaker, es posible la mia es: Server version: 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: tal vez puedas cambiar `ORDER BY W.fecha` por  `ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(W.fecha,  '%Y-%m%-%d' )` vi que también funciona